# How do I move a point without affecting other points/plains?

Tags: modeling

I have extruded a plane many times, and I want to grab and move one point to change the shape of a paticular plane, but when I attempt to do this, It affects all planes in the figure. How can I fix this?

Unexpected Result: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiOdN_mgNzY)

Comment: This is called [proportional edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/it/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/proportional_edit.html), and there are many questions about here, and I'm fairly certain there are duplicates of your problem. I can't find one close enough at this time though, but you can toggle proportional edit with the **O** key.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the proportional editing mode.[image]